# Bergman space $L_a^2(\mathbb C)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I claim that the Bergman space $L_a^2(\mathbb C)$ is the zero space. Is this true? If it is, how can I prove that every non-constant  entire function is not in $L^2$?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you please show what you tried so far? This would add some context to your question

Comment: What does the $a$ mean?  Is this a weight on the inner product?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer, assuming that you are considering the unweighted $L^2$ norm.  If you tell me what $a$ is, I can make an edit addressing that case.

Without loss of generality, assume $f(0) = 1$ (we can shift and scale $f$ if not).

Then

$\begin{align*}
1 &= |f(0)|\\
&=\left|\frac{1}{\pi r^2} \int_{D(r)} f(z) dA\right|\\
&\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi r^2}} \left[ \int_{D(r)} |f(z)|^2 dA\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align*}$

So we see for any positive constant $r$, $\lVert f \rVert_{L^2(D(r))} \geq \sqrt{\pi} r$, which then implies that $f$ is not in $L^2(\mathbb{C})$.

Let me know if any part of this is unclear to you.

Comment: The $a$ in $L^2_a(\mathbb{C})$ indicates that this is the collection of functions analytic in $\mathbb{C}$ that also satisfy the $L^2$ condition with respect to Lebesgue area measure.